# Vue JS best approach to wait for value in mounted hook

Tags: vue.js

In my Vue component I want to fetch work orders via axios. To do that, I need a user id, which is loaded via a computed property.

Just calling my method 'loadWorkorders' in the mounted lifecycle hook, results in the computed property not being available yet. So I want to check if this computed property is available, if not, just wait a few milliseconds and try again. Repeat the same cycle until it is available.

What is the best approach to handle this? Now I'm just waiting for a second and this seems to work, but I'm looking for a more robust approach.

My code:

```
    export default {
  name: "MyWorkorders",
  mounted() {
    if (this.user) {
      this.loadWorkorders();
    } else {
      setTimeout(this.loadWorkorders(), 1000);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      workOrders: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadWorkorders() {
      axios
        .get(`/workorders/load-user-workorders/${this.user.id}`)
        .then((res) => {
          this.workOrders = res.data.workorders;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
  },
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.getters.getUser;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: So in your this.loadWorkorders, you're using one of the properties of this.user. I guess there are a few ways of going about this, but it's quite difficult without knowing the full sequence of events.. At a guess you could call loadWorkorders straight after you've loaded the user. E.g. await this.loadUser; await this.loadWorkorders(); .Why isn't this.user available yet?

Comment: You need to know the exact moment when data is ready, and this is solved with promises. The question lacks the necessary code

Comment: Are you using Vue 2 or Vue 3?

Comment: Thanks already for your replies. I've added my full code to clarify. I'm using Vue 3.

Comment: @Pieter Did you ever find a way to do it?

Comment: @e4rthdog I changed my approach. I used to get the current user from my store, but now the user id is processed in my routes. So my url would be something like '/workorders/load-user-workorders/1', where '1' represents user id 1. In this way, my user id is immediately available via the route params property.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vue 3, consider using [Async Components](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html), which are also related to the [Suspense](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html) built-in component. (at the time of this post, Suspense is an experimental feature, however Async Components are stable)

If you are using Vue 2, take a look at [this part of the documentation about handling loading state in Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Handling-Loading-State).

If you do not want to invest in these solutions because your use case is very, very simple -- you can try the following simple solution:

```html
<template>
  <template v-if="loading">
    loading...
  </template>
  
  <template v-else-if="loaded">
    <!-- your content here -->
  </template>
  
  <template v-else-if="error">
    error
  </template>
</template>
```

I have made this [runnable example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) for demonstration. Of course, the templates for loading and error states can be made more complex if required.